# Update partial view after edit

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, asp.net-ajax

I have the following index:

```
<div id='addProduct'>
   @{ Html.RenderPartial("Create", new BoringStore.Models.Product()); }
</div>

<div id='productList'>
    @{ Html.RenderPartial("ProductListControl", Model.Products); }
</div>
```

The partial Create view contains an invisible div which is used to create a new product.
After doing so the partial view ProductListControl is updated.

Now I want to do so with an edit function.
Problem: It's not possible to integrate the edit page while loading the index because at this moment I don't know which product the user wants to edit.

My thought:
I'd like to call my existing edit view in an jquery modal (not the problem) so the user can perform changes.
After saving the modal is closed (still not the problem- I could handle this) and the ProductListControl is updated (here's my problem ... :().

How am I able to do so?
I've seen some tutorials but I'd like to keep it as clean & easy as possible. 
Most of them are using dom manipulating and get feedback from the server (controller) by a JsonResult.
If possible I'd like to stick to the razor syntax, no pure JavaScript or jquery and if possible I'd like to avoid JsonResults.

Comment: You basically want to update the product list via ajax (when creating a new product), without using any javascript, jquery or json results?

Comment: Well, I don't know if that's possible. That's why I'm asking you guys. Thought there would be an implemented mechanism in asp.net MVC 3 or something else.
The problem I have with the javascript stuff is that I have to code twice (for example how the index page is displayed: I first have to code how the page is displayed when loaded for the first time (asp.net Razor), then I have to code JavaScript methods which manipulate those data after the form is submitted ... Hoped that there is a) a cleaner solution which costs less time or b) a framework to do so ...)

Comment: I just wanted to clarify your requirements, I posted an answer - hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

One way might be to use the Ajax.BeginForm for your create product view.

The Ajax.BeginForm accepts a number of AjaxOptions, one being the UpdateTargetId (your DOM id, in this case your productlist div), more info [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.ajax.ajaxoptions%28v=vs.108%29.aspx).

Then in your product controller code you can return a partial view, with the product list. So for example:

Index.cshtml

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("AjaxSave", "Product", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "GET", UpdateTargetId = "productList", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace }))
{ 
    // your form
    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Save" />
    </p>
}

...

<div id="productList">...
</div>
```

ProductController.cs

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult AjaxSave(Product product)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // save products etc..
    }

    var allProducts = _productService.GetAllProducts();

    return PartialView("ProductListControl", allProducts);

}
```

There is a nice article on about this [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/stuartleeks/archive/2011/04/13/asp-net-mvc-partial-rendering-and-ajaxattribute.aspx).

Comment: It's not about creating, but editing.
I can't integrate the edit form into the index because when loading the index I don't already know which product the user wants to edit. :(

Comment: The article uses the example of an edit, then ajax updates the list. Maybe I'm not understanding what you need. Are your create/edit pages two separate partials? Could you post more code to help clarify